# Add To Cart Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, magento-community, merchant

I'm really at a loss. I have a web developer who basically 'does things we ask' then leaves us to our own devices, if something breaks, he won't fix it pretty much.

We asked him to install an extension so we comply with EU cookie law and since then, our add to cart button is not working. Hes uninstalled the extension but still no luck.

If we use the 'quick view' add to cart button, it works fine as per our theme but not on the main product pages. Is anyone able to help please? I'm ok with editing code when copied/pasted but I have very little coding knowledge.

Website is motif8.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the Add to Cart is working fine. I was able to add a configurable product from the category view and the product detail view pages.

You do have some serious speed tuning that needs to be done, but the Add to Cart is working for me on the Main Product pages.

You might need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: This.  Works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Checked my error log and it was showing syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in my upsell.phtml, appears I'd cocked something up when changing upsell text.